# Class Diagram for a Quiz

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to make a **Year Question Quiz** game in C#. I need help with solving the problem on how to have questions in different categories.

A **Quiz** consists of a question and an answer. But let’s say I want to have the Quiz to be in different categories. The categories I want are **sports**, **history** and **people**.

How should I design the class diagram for this quiz? What is the best way to solve the problem?
The class diagram below is on how I think to solve the problem. But I don’t think my solution is good. 
And I don’t know why the classes **Sports**, **History** and **People** should inheritance from Quiz and what instance variable should those classes contain? I could solve the problem without inheritance but the assignment I am doing says it is a requirement to use inheritance.

[image]

Comment: The categories should not be modeled as classes, but simply as a text property of the Quiz class.

Comment: Is that your solution or a requirement of this assignment? If the requirement says that Sports, History, and People inherit from quiz, then that's probably because those 3 topics are types of quizzes. Consider the following question to help you answer yours: What methods and properties do all quizzes share?

Comment: That is my solution for the assignment. There is no requirement that the categories, Sports, History and People should inherit from Quiz. But I have to use inheritance somehow in the assigment.

Comment: If that's what the assignement says, then it's okay. But usually you only use inheritance if you somehow add or change the behaviour. As it stands now, Sports, People and History work *exactly* the same as Quiz, so usually you would not need to inherit anything.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good so far, though I'd add some methods and classes like this:

```
interface IQuiz {
      public List<Question> getQuestions();
      public float scoreQuiz();
}

class Answer { string answer; }
class Question { 
      List<Answer> potentialAnswers;
      Answer correctAnswer;
}

class SportsQuiz : IQuiz { }
class PeopleQuiz : IQuiz { }
class HistoryQuiz : IQuiz { }
```

Comment: Pretty bloated solution... I don't see why Question & Answer should be separate classes.

Comment: It's so you can share answers between questions. It's actually the exact opposite of bloated from a data perspective.  It also keeps things cleaner.

Comment: I wouldn't use an `interface IQuiz` but an `abstract class Quiz` so I could for example have a `protected List<Question> Questions {get;set;}` in only one place. Or additionaly. And `Quiz` implements `IQuiz`.

Comment: I probably would too but this is an academic study, not an actual solution. He's new so I didn't want to complicate things for him ;)

Answer (score 1):

One possible (simple) way to do this:

```
public class Quiz
{
    public string Question { get; private set; }
    public string Answer { get; private set;}

    public Quiz(string question, string answer)
    {
        Question = question;
        Answer = answer;
    }
}
```

And then later:

```
// Create a dictionary
Dictionary<string, List<Quiz>> quizDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Quiz>>();

// Create a category
List<Quiz> sportsQuiz = new List<Quiz>();
// Add questions & answers to the category
sportsQuiz.Add(new Quiz("Whats the question?", "It's the answer"));

// Add the category to your quiz dictionary
quizDictionary.Add("Sports", sportsQuiz);

// Select a category
List<Quiz> randomQuiz = quizDictionary["Sports"];

// Do something with the category
Quiz randomQA = randomQuiz[0];

Ask(randomQA.Question);
if (answer == randomQA.Answer)
    // correct answer
else
    // wrong answer
```